# Mod rewrite apache

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I want to rewite following urls

url format to be redirected is like
`localhost/project/share-file/share-id/path-to-file`

share-id varies with all urls but all share-id is 32 characters

path can be of any levels 
`eg: root/abc , root/abc/xyz , root/zz/aa/bb and so on`

i want following redirect rules
`orginal link:  localhost/project/share-file/ae34chfj/root/ab`
 
`Redirected to: localhost/project/share-file-view.php?shareId=ae34chfj&path=root/abc`

Another example of redirect is
`Original link: localhost/share-file/gh12a23f/root/abc/x`

`Redirected to: localhost/project/share-file-view.php?shareId=gh12a23f&path=root/abc/x`

I do not know the number of levels of path. Is there any rewrite rule to do so. Or there is any way around.

Comment: Did you try anything yourself?

Comment: I thought of sending whole share-id/path at a single parameter and then to use string manupulation to seprate share-id and path in php

Comment: @ArupRakshit this question is not ruby related so i asked it here. I just started ruby and surely would ask ruby related questions in ruby forum

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your htaccess has to be in your **project** folder for this rule:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /project/

RewriteRule ^share-file/([A-Za-z0-9]{32})/(.+)$ share-file-view.php?shareId=$1&path=$2 [L]
```

Comment: I copied the rule to .htaccess and type http://localhost/project/share-directory/70cbPF858ZoGRVyIlXIns3uoxGXZpNHS/root/a in browser. 
It returns "The requested URL /project/share-directory/70cbPF858ZoGRVyIlXIns3uoxGXZpNHS/root/a was not found on this server."

Comment: In your question, you said **share-file** and not **share-directory**. Also, i added upper letters for the *share-id*

Comment: I changed the rewrite rule to
RewriteRule ^share-directory/([A-Za-z0-9]{32})/(.+)$ share-file-view.php?shareId=$1&path=$2 [L]
But still same error

Comment: Thank you for you time. I got it. Problem was due to capital letters in share-id